# VictoriaMetrics response from UI does not converge with API response

Tags: python, prometheus, promql, insomnia, victoriametrics

I'm trying to send request to VictoriaMetrix by API HTTP (from python and Insomnia - same problems), but response which I got do not agree with the response received through UI.

**VictoriaMetrcis**

```
PromQL request:
avg_over_time(node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate{container="test"}[1m])
From 2024-01-17 03:00:00, To 2024-01-17 03:30:00
Result: "value": [
      1705451400,
      "0.23692520737666"]
```

[image: Screen]

**Insomnia**

```
GET: http://my-test-victoria.com:8000/api/v1/query
Query:
query = avg_over_time(node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate{container="test"}[1m])
time = 2024-01-17T03:00:00.00Z
Result: "value": [
    1705460400,
    "0.01631004441833"]
```

Screen: [image: Screen]

**Python code fragment** (using library "requests" for connect with API)

```python
request_params = {
    "query": query['query'],
    "time": input_datetime
}
responce = http_request(prometheus_common['url'] + "/api/v1/query", request_params)
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?
Result in UI is correct, but HTTP-requests is not.

I tried add params from the [VictoriaMetrcis docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/url-examples.html#apiv1query) and the [Prometheus docs](https://prometheus-api-client-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/prometheus_api_client.html)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description of what you mean by *"Result in UI is correct, but HTTP-requests is not"*. What is the expected result and what result are you getting? Also, please show more of your python code, it's hard to tell what you're doing and where it's going wrong.

Comment: First element in the `value` is a timestamp. The differ by two and a half hours. No surprise query results are different.

Comment: @markalex, shure! How can i get the same timestamp in Insomnia?
I indicated in the request to another time: 
time = 2024-01-17T03:00:00.00Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@markalex, was right, thanks! Timestamps was diff.

1. It is necessary to indicate the final date+time but not the initial!
2. Timezone from insomnia and python brokes request.
   Result:

> time = 2024-01-17T03:30:00+03:00

Right time (end) and hard indication of the timezone

Answer (score 0):

[VictoriaMetrics UI](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#vmui) may send request to one of the following APIs depending on the context:

- [/api/v1/query_range](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#range-query) for building a graph for the given query on the selected time range.
- [/api/v1/query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#instant-query) for returning a single result per each matching time series at the end of the selected time range when switching to JSON or Table view.

It is advised enabling [network panel in the web browser](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network) when you need to understand which particular requests to which APIs are sent by [VMUI](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#vmui) when it performs various actions.